# Order by Timestamp in Spring data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, timestamp, sql-order-by

I am trying to fetch data from a table `Products` where i am using `findByIdOrderByTransactionDateDesc()` of Spring data JPA in my spring boot application. As my transaction date is of type timestamp i am not able to get the correct order of the fetched record of latest timestamp.

```
findByIdOrderByProductsDetails_DateDesc();
```

My **Products** class is:

```
@Entity
public class Products {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private float price;  
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductDetails> productsDetails;}
```

and **ProductDetails** class is:

```
@Entity
public class ProductDetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "transaction_date")
    private Timestamp transactionDate;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Products product;
}
```

Comment: Please show some code and the generated SQL query

Comment: What version of Spring boot/Spring Data are you using? What database are you trying to connect?

Comment: As @SimonMartinelli suggest, add the code for the ```Products``` class, the corresponding repository interface and for example some output data in order to understand better the context.

Comment: Could you please consider adding `Products` model?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli added model classes that i am using

Answer (score 1):

productsDetails is a OneToMany relationship and you cannot navigate using Spring Data repository methods.

You have to use a query:

```
@Query("select p from Products join productsDetails d where p.id = :id order by d.transactionDate desc")
findByIdOrderByProductsDetails_DateDesc(Integer id);
```